# How can I randomise the magnitude spectrum of an image whilst keeping the phase unchanged?

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I am trying to randomise the magnitude component of the spectrum of the following [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7bk7.png). I was thinking of using `numpy.random.rand()` for the generation of random values however I am not sure how to go about it. Is someone able to explain how I can proceed?
The following is the code to obtain the magnitude spectrum of the image attached.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img_tp = cv2.imread('testpattern.png', 0)
f_tp = np.fft.fft2(img_tp)
fshift_tp = np.fft.fftshift(f_tp)
mag_spectrum_tp = 20*np.log(np.abs(fshift_tp))
plt.imshow(mag_spectrum_tp)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see how that would be useful in any way.  The phase information doesn't have any real meaning without the magnitude.  Theoretically, you can combine unrelated magnitude and phase values by doing something like this:

```
f_mag = np.abs( fft_result1 )
f_phase = np.angle( fft_result2 )
combined = np.multiply(f_mag, np.exp(1j*f_phase))
img = np.fft.iff2(combined)
```

but the results are pretty much going to be garbage.

Comment: This is not related to what I am asking. I want to see what happens when I randomise the magnitude component only and then I was gonna do the same for the phase.

Comment: That's exactly what I've showed you.  My example shows pulling the magnitude and phase from two separate FFTs, but you can just as easily have the magnitude come from a random number generator.  Again, the results are going to be garbage, but it is possible.  Random values in the time domain rarely produce anything useful.

Comment: Really, your question is "how can I combine a magnitude matrix and an unrelated phase matrix and run them through an inverse FFT"?  And that's what I've shown you.

Comment: you are right I did not fully understand your answer at first. I accepted your answer

Comment: Personally, I'd be curious to find out what you learn.